# EXTRACT XML IN ORACLE 11 G USING XMLTYPE OPERATIONS

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, xmltype

I've been working on Oracle 11g since a couple months, so don't have enough experience, thank you for helping me out of this. I'm trying to read a big XML file and get just 2 values of this, the thing is that the document I read is kind big. So let me explain you what I'm doing:

Creating a table for storing the xml:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_table OF XMLType;
```

Then I read the document for getting it into the table:

```
PROCEDURE prc_insertXmlFile( dir VARCHAR2, file VARCHAR2) IS
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO xml_table
  VALUES (XMLType(bfilename(dir, file),
          nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Now, this is an extract of the document(the insert was ok) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="VehicleTripSummary http://lol/someServer?%2lol4%2FVehicleTripSummary&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rs%3ASessionID=prfwnw554uqweiz0c45eviftfu5&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="VehicleTripSummary" txtReportTitle="Vista Viaje por Vehículo (Resumen)" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="VehicleTripSummary">
  <table1 textbox8="Publicado por:" User_Description="Operaciones qwwwq" textbox5="Grupo de  Vehículo:" VehicleGroup_Description="Grupo de Vehiculos-qweqe qweqe." textbox16="Período:" LocalTimestampRange="2015-02-03 00:00 .. 2015-02-03 23:59"/>
  <tblTripDetails Distance_Abbreviation="Distance(Km)" textbox17="Duración" textbox25="Ultima Conocida Odómetro" Textbox27="Ultima Conocida Hs. Motor" textbox47="Descripción de Vehículo" textbox1="Registro" textbox2="Núm. de Viajes" textbox3="Total" textbox11="Promedio" textbox19="Total" textbox14="Promedio" textbox18="Núm. de Choferes" textbox20="Fecha" textbox24="Lectura" Textbox28="Fecha" Textbox21="Lectura" textbox42="Totales:" textbox44="1987" textbox45="7040" textbox48="287:11:06">
    <Detail_Collection>
      <Detail Vehicle_Description_1="A144 CL149627" Vehicle_Registration="CL149627" NoOfTrips="0" TotalDistance="0" AverageDistance="0" TotalDuration_Description="00:00:00" AverageDuration_Description="00:00:00" NoOfDrivers="0" LastKnownOdometer="2015-01-30 10:02:58" LastKnownOdometerLocalTimestamp="46" Textbox29="--" Textbox31="--"/>
      <Detail Vehicle_Description_1="A38 CL124335 " Vehicle_Registration="CL124335" NoOfTrips="3" TotalDistance="0" AverageDistance="0" TotalDuration_Description="00:08:03" AverageDuration_Description="00:02:41" NoOfDrivers="0" LastKnownOdometer="2015-02-04 16:13:35" LastKnownOdometerLocalTimestamp="283252" Textbox29="--" Textbox31="--"/>
.
.
.
   </Detail_Collection>
  </tblTripDetails>
</Report>
```

NOW, what I want is read this to get the value Datail/Vehicle_Registration and Datail/TotalDistance.
I´m doing this:

```
SELECT extractValue(OBJECT_VALUE,'/Report/tblTripDetail/Detail_Collection/Detail[1]//Vehicle_Registration') Detalles
FROM xml_table;
```

But I couldn't get what the data I wanted.

Thanks in advance.

CHECK THIS OUT: [XMLTYPE OPERATIONS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb04cre.htm#i1030920)

Comment: Please remove the caps and show us what you are getting so we know what is actually happening.

Comment: Sorry sir, Actually I just get a row with no data when I executed the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution, hope it will be helpful for somebody! x)
The problem is with the xml name space, we have to remove it by doing this:
[THE SOLUTION](https://jvzoggel.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/remove-namespace-xmltype-xml-database/)

Then I accessed to the data I need with this code:

```
PROCEDURE PRC_PRINCIPAL IS
  y xmltype;
  x XMLType := XMLType(bfilename('PRUEBASTALLERXML', 'VehicleTripSummary.xml'),
          nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'));
BEGIN
  SELECT XMLTRANSFORM(x, x.stylesheet)
  INTO Y
  FROM XMLSTYLESHEETS x
  WHERE x.CODE = 'REMNAM';
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Detail/@Vehicle_Registration') as name


    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(y,'/Report/tblTripDetails/Detail_Collection//Detail'))) p
    ) LOOP
   htp.p(r.name);

  END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/Report/tblTripDetail/Detail_Collection/Detail[1]//@Vehicle_Registration
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I still getting no data :/

Comment: My bad, I edited the path. Vehicle_Registration is an attribute, so need to use @.

Comment: I think it was another mistake I had. But still no data :/ Do think it can be the way I created the table ?  Because I get an empty row